# Terminology question about parellelized morphisms

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Given $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$, what is the correct name for the morphism $h: A \times C \to B \times D$ defined as 
$$
h:(a,b) \mapsto (f(a),g(b))?
$$

Comment: It's also called *split* or *pair*, and in Haskell is denoted `(&&&)`. Your *parallelized* intuition is also mentioned on the first page here: https://github.com/alhassy/CatsCheatSheet/blob/master/CheatSheet.pdf ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's called the [product morphism of $f$ and $g$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Product_of_Morphisms).